# jQuery Submit not working with <a>

Tags: jquery, html, form-submit

I am trying to make a link submit a form. How come when I name a submit input element `submit`, the link no longer works?

```
 //breaks form submission
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />

 //does not break form submission
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="xsubmit" />
```

In Chrome I receive the following error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'submit' of object #<HTMLFormElement> is not a function
```

NOT Working

```
<p>Type 'correct' to validate.</p>
  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />

    <a id="btn_submit">
        <span id="txt_submit">Submit</span>
    </a>
  </form>

<script>

$("#btn_submit").click(function() {
     $("form").submit();
    });

    $("form").submit(function() {

    });
</script>
```

WORKING

```
 <p>Type 'correct' to validate.</p>
  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="xsubmit" />

    <a id="btn_submit">
        <span id="txt_submit">Submit</span>
    </a>
  </form>

<script>

$("#btn_submit").click(function() {
     $("form").submit();
    });

    $("form").submit(function() {

    });
</script>
```

Comment: You've posted the same code twice. Can you show us your `<submit>` code?

Comment: name="submit" works for me in Chrome. What browser are you using? - @JamWaffles it's not the same code. xsubmit versus submit name attribute on button.

Comment: @JamWaffles - I am seeing something weird here. His double code post brings up a valid point. See this fiddle. The form submit fails with `Property 'submit' of object #<HTMLFormElement> is not a function` http://jsfiddle.net/r4cLW/1/ (Chrome15 here). If he changes the name of the submit button to xsubmit this no longer happens.

Comment: name="submit" is not working for me on Chrome.  I get this error Uncaught TypeError: Property 'submit' of object #<HTMLFormElement> is not a function

Comment: I did not posted the same code twice, i just want to show that the <input type="submit" /> is different. So in order to have better understanding, I posted the whole coding.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"Submit" is a reserved word. It conflicts with javascript. Just change the name of the input to something else.

From the jQuery documentation on the method [submit()](http://api.jquery.com/submit/):

> Forms and their child elements should not use input names or ids that
>   conflict with properties of a form, such as submit, length, or method.
>   Name conflicts can cause confusing failures. For a complete list of
>   rules and to check your markup for these problems, see DOMLint.

Comment: It isn't in the reserved word or potential reserved word list. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words

Comment: My bad. It conflicts not with js but jQuery:
Forms and their child elements should not use input names or ids that conflict with properties of a form, such as submit, length, or method. Name conflicts can cause confusing failures. 
http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: I think this is leading us to this strange behavior but is not quite the definitive answer.  It is a javascript "keyword" as defined here http://www.quackit.com/javascript/javascript_reserved_words.cfm

Comment: Thx. Just checked. It conflicts with native js as well.

Answer (score 5):

Two changes:

```
$(function () {

$("#btn_submit").click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $("form").submit();
    });

    $("form").submit(function() {

    });

});
```

First, include the bind in the document.ready handler `$(function () {...});` 
Second, add the preventDefault call on the event to stop the normal anchor functionality.

Comment: You don't actually need to bind from within `$(document).ready()`. Also, I was about 20 seconds away from posting my answer which has the same `e.prevenDefault()` solution as yours, so +1!

Comment: You DO need to bind within document ready, at least if you do so without using `.live()` or `.on()`, since it's quite possible that when the call to bind the event is executed, the element may not exist in the DOM yet, so won't actually bind anything.

Comment: Good point. I'm so used to putting all my scripts at the bottom of my page that I forgot about that.

Comment: I think this actually misses the point of the OP's question. He wants to know why naming his submit button `submit` breaks submission.